# Color overlay a responsive image with Compass?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, compass-sass

I don't have control over the HTML that I'm styling, so each img is nested in an li.  The li has padding, which cannot be changed to a margin because of a complex responsive grid system. And, yes, since it's responsive, the size of the image might change.
Here's the demo: [Play with this gist on SassMeister.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8851504)

Sass:

```
.active {
  border: grey solid 4px;
  opacity: .2;
 }

 ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
 }

img {
  width: 100%;
}

#thumbs {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img class="active" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I make a color overlay effect on the .active image?

Background color applied to the li parent is messy because of the padding, and I am having trouble figuring out how to create a pseudo element that's the same size as the image.

Edit: I thought maybe I could achieve this with an offset border, see [this gist on SassMeister.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8977944)  But I would need to do some math to make the border width and offset exactly half the width (or height) of the image.  Can I do that with Sass?

Sass:

```
.active {
  border: grey solid 4px;
  opacity: .2;
  outline: 160px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  outline-offset: -160px;
 }


 ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
 }

img {
  width: 100%;
}

#thumbs {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img class="active" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvXOVCJkz-VEZjmFxh0dgKUZ5z6Ojg7doS64g8FUmDsdEE-6_R">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are good SassMeister gists, but please also include the HTML and Sass directly here in this question.

Comment: You cannot do this using a pseudo element because an `img` is a replaced element. Use a sibling element absolutely positioned over the image

Comment: I see.  But is it possible to add a sibling to the HTML with Sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something working, [try this on for size](http://jsfiddle.net/J3QF2/). It only works if you can add a class to the `<li>`.

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't allow any form of parent selection, so you can't say 'give me any `<li>` containing an `<img>` with the class `<active>` :( That's javascript turf

Unless you want to stuff around adding overlays with javascript, why not apply the tint color you want to the parent element `<li>`, then replace the `padding` with `margins` so the colour doesn't stick out, as it's obscured by the image within. Then apply the `opacity` to the `img.active` like you have. I think you were on the right track with the first idea.

The only control you really get over opacity is either the element itself or it's background color, as in `rgba(red, blue, green, opacity)`. This means if you apply the BG colour to the image, it will be obscured by this image, and as any changes to transparency effect the whole thing.

Comment: I'd agree, what I need is JS turf.  I can't swap the padding for margins (that was my original thought), so I ended up with a JS solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/msqcB